Python directory settings: Path(__file__).resolve().parent
When defining the project root in Python3 scripts, some IDE and guidebooks suggest PROJECT_ROOT = Path(__file__).resolve().parent, but PROJECT_ROOT = Path('.') works fine too.
What are the differences between the statements?
from pathlib import Path

PROJECT_ROOT = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
# OR
PROJECT_ROOT = Path('.')
# Any differences?


Path('.') has nothing to do with where the project files are. It's a relative path for the current working directory.

@user2357112
Thank you very much for the short answer.  After conducting some experiments, as suggested by juanpa.arrivillaga, I realized that it has "nothing to do with."

Path('.')

Means the current working directory.
Path(__file__).resolve().parent

Means the parent path of the current file (of whatever module that line is in).
These are not necessarily the same at all. For a very simple example, suppose simply you run the script from some directory other than the project root. Or suppose somewhere in the code you have already done:
os.chdir("/foo/bar")

Then Path('.') will be /foo/bar.
For that matter, Path(__file__).resolve().parent will not necessarily be the project root. You have to take care to understand what you are doing -- using your knowledge of the directory structure, to make sure it is actually getting at the project root.

I appreciate the comprehensible examples.  I tried some test scripts and grokked the difference.  Thank you!
